# What is the difference between “area”, “zone”, and “site”?

Tags: word-usage

Is there any difference between *area*, *zone*, and *site*?

If there is some difference between them?

When do I have to use (nor not use) each of these constructions?

Comment: Have you looked at dictionary defintions? What did you find? What is unclear?

Comment: And in addition to what @AndrewLeach said: what is the context? All these three words have specific meanings in many fields, and their meanings might not be comparable between fields.

Comment: @AndrewLeach : all of them have the Same meanings. I just want to know WHEN I have to use each of them.

Comment: You might have looked them up in a Persian dictionary.

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri, they do _not_ all have the same meaning. If you look them up in an _English_ dictionary, you will see that the explanations for all three words differ.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, Which English dictionary do you recommend?

Comment: Any will do: Merriam-Webster, Oxford, Cambridge, American Heritage Dictionary, dictionary.com, etc.

Comment: An excellent question, which I can't do justice to but will comment: an area can be any size, a zone is a 'very special' area (it's a less common word too) and a site is also a synonym of location, so more specific and towards the point-like.

Comment: The O.P. might want to check out [ell.se]. (@Amirreza: By the way, if you ask this question there, be sure to include at least one dictionary definition for each word. That way, no one will ask you, "What did the dictionary say?" and the community will be better able to understand what exactly is confusing you, and where you need additional guidance. That advice goes for both sites.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on context. But in general, an *area* is a region or part of a town, world, etc. where you live. A *site* is an area of ground on which you build a building, a small town, etc. It could also refer to a place where an event is taking place.

> That is the site where ogres were slaughtered by the King of Far Far Away.

A *zone* is a restricted area, used for a particular purpose or use.

> War zone. Pedestrian zone.

Comment: Do I have to use "Area" on "Nature" context?

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri Example? Please.

Comment: "You can have a trip on this area (Jungle)."

Comment: 'area' is good for a 'natural' place. 'zone' is good for a man-made  area, and 'site' leans towards a man-made thing but you can have instances like 'the site of the sink hole'.